# What is the meaning of a comma outside a string

Tags: ruby, math

I was tasked with taking a string that is using reverse polish notation and evaluating it but I can't understand the code block after the if statement

```
 def evaluate(string)
   array = tokens(string)
   symbols = [:+,:-,:*,:/]
   new_array = []
   array.each do |x|
     if symbols.include?(x)            
       b,a = new_array.pop, new_array.pop
       new_array << symbol_math(x, a, b)
     else
       new_array << x
     end
   end
   new_array[0]
 end

 def symbol_math symbol, a, b
   return a+b if symbol == :+
   return a-b if symbol == :-
   return a*b if symbol == :*
   return a.to_f/b if symbol == :/
 end
```

I get that your checking if the character is in the symbols array and if it is you remove it and give it as an argument to symbol_math.What I don't understand is how `b,a = new_array.pop, new_array.pop` works.

Comment: In this context it's the same as `b = new_array.pop; a = new_array.pop`. It's generally called *parallel assignment*. It's mainly used like so: `a,b = b,a`, which is equivalent to `temp = a; a = b; b = temp`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland +1 for carefully adding the word "[I]n this context".

Comment: not sure why this would not just be `a,b = new_array.pop(2)`? seems odd to use the reverse variables and back to back calls to `pop`

Comment: thank you i dont know why this confused me so much